# Sort a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[ ["5", "France", "Paris", "..."], ["7", "UK", "London"], ["1", "..."], ["8", "..."] ]
```

Now I need to sort this one array so that the individual entries are in order like this:

```
[ ["1", "..."], ["5", "France",  "Paris"], ["7", "UK", "London"], ["8", "..."] ]
```

How would I go about that in PHP?

The other answer that @YourCommonSense is referring to does it in Java and not in PHP

Comment: Use underscore js can help you http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Thanks @Saineshwar!

Comment: I edited the question it should no longer be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do it in Javascript

```
var arr = [ ["5", "France", "Paris", "..."], ["7", "UK", "London"], ["1", "..."], ["8", "..."] ]
console.log(arr);
arr.sort((el1,el2) => {
    return el1[0] - el2[0];
});

// Non-ES6 equivalent
arr.sort(function(el1,el2) {
    return el1[0] - el2[0];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[["5", "France", "Paris", "..."], ["7", "UK", "London"], …]
[["1", "..."], ["5", "France", "Paris", "..."], ["7", …], …]
```

Comment: What does el1 and el2 stand for?

Comment: `.sort()` receives a [comparingFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which tells it how to decide the order of two elements. The two elements in this case are arrays themselves since your original array contains arrays inside

Comment: And do I have to define el1 and el2 or will it do that automatically?

Comment: The callback (`function(el1,el2)...`) will be called multiple times when sorting and each time `el1`, `el2` will be provided so no you don't need to define it yourself

Comment: Good, thanks. I read the article for comparingFunction too and it helped me as well! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One solution PHP oriented

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
print_r($array);
```

Result

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 1
>               [1] => ...
>           )
>
> ```
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 5
>         [1] => France
>         [2] => Paris
>         [3] => ...
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 7
>         [1] => UK
>         [2] => London
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 8
>         [1] => ...
>     ) )
> ```